# How do you get camel to create a queue before it's produced to?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

My setup is this: -

- activemq 5.8
- JBoss Fuse ESB 6.0

Queues are only automatically created when a consumer is added, i.e., in a `<from uri="activemq:my-queue" />`, or when a message is sent to a queue that doesn't exist.

In my case this is part of an error handler and it is the DLQ I have a problem with. It doesn't have any consumers so is only created when a message is sent. I'd like to be able to pre-instantiate the queue so that I am able to check it's associated MBean attributes (via Jolokia). Obviously it doesn't exist until a message goes onto the DLQ (hopefully never) which means that there is no MBean to query.

Now I know I can create the queue directly in activemq config but for various reasons that's a difficult path to follow.

So the question is this...

How do you get camel to create a queue before it's produced to and it doesn't have a consumer?

I tried defining `<endpoint uri="activemq:my-dlq" />` but I think that's just clutching at straws as it only provides a hook to create a consumer or producer and doesn't actually create the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure activemq with a number of startup destinations it should create. You do this in the activemq.xml configuration file.

The ActiveMQ web site have a bit of details here

- http://activemq.apache.org/configure-startup-destinations.html

But their website has recently been re-generated and some links are broken. But the pointer is that you setup these destinations in the broker.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this was the proper way to do it, was trying to circumvent some existing project & process constraints using camel (without hacking). Thanks for the feedback; given that you're the source of all my camel knowledge I'll take this as the definitive answer!